# Selenium web driver gets stuck in command: page_source

Tags: javascript, java, python, html, selenium

I'm loading a webpage and then clicking on a series of java links to show some extra information in the page and then save the page html. The code works perfectly fine for most of the similar pages in the website, but there are a few pages (as the one in the code) that after clicking on java links in them, the code gets stuck on getting page_source.

I've let the code sit on the line for a few days, but it doesn't move on or give any error.

If I remove the part of the code that's clicking on java links the code works fine again, but I have no idea what in the page changes that might cause this problem. and since there is no error or any indication, I can't think of a way to skip that page.

Here's a simplified version of the code with the webpage that causes the issue:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://myanimelist.net/animelist/jonwoo&status=2&order=0")

javas=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,\"javascript:void(0)\")]")

for java in javas:
   try:
      java.click()
   except:
      webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(java).click(java).perform()

urlstr = driver.page_source
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: instead of using a blanket exception catch, why not narrow it down to the error that line throws?  I imagine your script is getting hung up on the blank except and thus never gets to the page_source function call.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked and it exits the loop and gets to the page_source line.

Comment: What happens after `urlstr = driver.page_source` ? i.e. How are you sure that that's where it gets stuck?

Comment: @Josh well, in actual code I save urlstr to a file. but to check simply, I added a line print("done"). it never got there...

Comment: Hmm, ok, I've tried to run it myself (using C# instead) and my program is failing at the same point. I think the problem probably lies with the fact that the page source is so huge (I make it 24,285 words / 286,359 characters) and as webdriver returns its own version of the page source anyway, it's probably a much bigger string you're dealing with. I would suggest trying not to pass this page source to a variable...

Comment: @Josh Thanks, is there a way to save it directly? also, some pages are much lighter compared to this one and the code still gets stuck there while it works for much heavier pages. I looked for hours but couldn't find a difference between those that work and those that don't!